# Creating dynamically named variables in a for loop in R and assign value of zero to all new variables

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to create a suite of dynamically named new variables using a for loop, and assigning each variable a value of zero.

I am not sure why the code below is not working.

```
weather <- data.frame("TAVG" = 51:52, "Location" = c("USA", "Canada"))

for (i in 30:60) {
  weather <- mutate(weather, paste0("hdd", i) = 0)
}
```

I'd greatly appreciate any advice or ideas about how to get this working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has to do with *quoting* within `dplyr`. The following should work.

```
for (i in 30:60) {
  weather <- mutate(weather, !!paste0("hdd", i) := 0)
}
```

Note that this might be easier to do using base R.

```
for (i in 30:60) {
  weather[paste0("hdd", i)] <- 0
}
```

Or just drop the loop.

```
weather[paste0("hdd", 30:60)] <- 0
```